# Images are not coming after converting JSON to PDF using XSL stylesheet

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Am converting JSON Objects to PDF using XSL stylesheet. I have images in my XSL but that is not coming in PDF.

Please find my below code for my `<img>` tag

```
<td>
<img><xsl:attribute name="src">./img/logo.png</xsl:attribute></img>
</td>
```

Am having my `logo.png` in `src\main\resource\img` directory.

Can anyone have any idea about it ??

Please find my java code which is converting JSON to PDF document

```
Transformer transformer;
try {
    transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xslPath)));
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException | TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e1) {
    throw ExceptionUtils.handle((Exception) e1);
}

DOMResult result = new DOMResult();

try {
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))), result);
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    throw ExceptionUtils.handle(e);
}


//Just for printing HTML Starts.......//
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 try {
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))), new StreamResult(writer));
} catch (TransformerException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
System.out.println("Output --->"+output);
//Just for printing HTML Ends.......//

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
try {
    renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:/WINDOWS/FONTS/ARIAL.TTF", true);
} catch (DocumentException e) {
    throw ExceptionUtils.handle(e);
}

Document resultDoc = (Document) result.getNode();
renderer.setDocument(resultDoc, "");
renderer.layout();
```

Am printing HTML and in HTML output am able to see images., its not printing..

Comment: Is your relative path correct? Is the HTML in src\main\resource (seems like that's where it should be based on the path starting with `./img`).

Comment: my relative path is correct and its not HTML file., am having this `<img>` tag in XSL file., and my XSL file and .png file both are in same directory.

Comment: If your XSLT and png are both in the same directory, have you tried changing your path to just `./logo.png`?

Comment: yes Daniel Haley.., i tried and its also not working. Am printing my output HTML., Am able to see image in HTML output but not coming in PDF